# Maximization of bilinear objective over convex body

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, non-convex-optimization

Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex compact body. Given the following optimization problem:

$$\max_{x \in C\\ \left\| v \right\|_2 \leq 1} \left< x, v \right>$$

where $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ denotes the dot product.

Is this problem considered to be convex or not? And how one would determine it?

Comment: The bilinear objective is an indefinite quadratic form and, thus, neither convex nor concave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An optimization problem is considered convex if you are *minimizing* a convex function over a convex feasible region. So you must ask yourself:

1. Is the function $-\langle x, v\rangle$ convex?
2. Is the set $C\times\{\|v\|\leqslant1\}$ convex? (**See edit below**)

A potentially helpful way to attack 1. is to consider the case when $n=1$ (so that $-\langle x,v\rangle=-xv$, where $x,v\in\mathbb{R}$).

**Edit**

The formal definition of a [convex optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization#Convex_optimization_problem) is a problem that can be expressed as

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & f(x) \\
\text{s.t.}\ & g_i(x)\leqslant 0\text{ for all }i=1,\dots,m
\end{array}
$$

where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $g_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ are convex functions for $i=1,\dots,m$. However given, any convex set $C$, the indicator function

$$ I_c(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x\in{C}, \\ \infty, &\text{else.}\end{cases} $$

is convex. Hence, if we are minimizing a convex function over a convex set, we can always (mathematically) represent our problem in the standard form above. Note that we are using the extended reals here, which is common in convex optimization (see *e.g.* Boyd's book).

Caveat: of course, the indicator function is useless for computation--you would need an algebraic description of the set $C$. But for definitions (as we're concerned with here), it will suffice.

Comment: You should delete the minus sign in your first point.

Comment: @vaoy No, I meant it to be there. Since I phrased my answer in terms of minimization, the OP’s model would become $\min-\langle x,v\rangle$ (_i.e._ minimizing the negative of the original objective function).

Comment: Ou sorry mate, didnt optimisation problem in the question was maximising, my bad. :)

Comment: If you fix one variable and try to solve for the other variable then yes, it's conex!
But why are looking at the intersection of a ball and $C$!? (it can be empty!)

Comment: Oops—see my edited answer in a minute

Comment: Keep in mind that the fucntion to be minimised is actually defined over $$\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$$ in the two variables $x$ and $y$

Comment: Then how one can determine convexity of such feasible region? (e.g. how would it look like!?)

Comment: It is convex beacuse $C$ is convex and $\{(x,y): ||y|| \leq 1\}$ is convex. And intersection of convex sets are convex.

Comment: The intesection of them, not the cross product!

Comment: Yes the intersection is convex.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1147208)

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. So the problem now is to determine whether the dot product is convex? So should i look at the hessain? (if you fix one variable then yes, it's convex since it's basically linear!)

Comment: If the hessian is positive semidefinite, then it is convex.

Comment: Your definition of a convex optimization problem is wrong; the constraint functions need to be convex.

Comment: @LinAlg see my edit